# How to open a href link in a FormToolkit of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

made a hyperlink but it is not opening any webpage.

```
toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
        form = toolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);
         form.setText("Hello, Abhishek Eclipse Form");
          GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
          form.getBody().setLayout(layout);
          final Hyperlink link = toolkit.createHyperlink(form.getBody(), 
            "Click here.", SWT.WRAP);
          link.setHref("http://www.google.com");
```

As per the above piece of code,how should I open the webPage in the FormToolkit view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hyperlink widget isn't like a browser link. It doesn't by itself know how to handle links. You work with it like a button, in that you listen for the click event and then do what you need to.

You can find examples on how to work with forms here:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html

Here is how you listen for link activation:

```
link.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkAdapter() {
   public void linkActivated(HyperlinkEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Link activated!");
   }
```

To actually replace the contents of the view with a web page is quite a bit more complicated. You would have to dispose of all widgets currently in the view (such as the hyperlink), then you would create a Browser widget and point it at the appropriate URL.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. Here are some options... (1) Use Browser control in your view to start with. The Browser already knows how to handle links and you have to deal primarily with html. (2) Open a browser in a separate view on activation of your hyperlink. Something like this... IWorkbenchBrowserSupport supoprt =
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport();
IWebBrowser browser = support.createBrowser("someId");
browser.openURL(new URL("http://www.eclipse.org"));

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used your previous response of adding and disposing the component and append browser and it worked .